# How to use Mockito "verify" with "eventually" of specs2?

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

I am writing a test with [specs2](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/) and [mockito](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) in Scala. The test should verify that a function `foo` running *asynchronously* calls `barMock.bar()`

In order to verify the `barMock.bar()` call I can use `verify` :

```
verify(barMock).bar()
```

Since `foo` is running asynchronously I should use `eventually` method to verify the call :

```
eventually {
  verify(barMock).bar()
}
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not compile and I had to add `success`

```
eventually {
  verify(barMock).bar()
  success
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of that `successs` ?

Comment: You are using `verify` wrong. Should be `verify(barMock).bar()`

Comment: Thanks. I am fixing the question. The actual code was correct though ...

Comment: correct code usually compiles ... ;)

Comment: If you expect anyone to be able to help with this, you gotta be waaay more specific than "code doesn't compile". It's weird to have to suggest this to someone with 40k rep., but ... check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not familiar with specs2 but shouldn't you be using `await` on the `foo` call and then asserting right away?

Comment: I do not think you can avoid using `success` there as the other options are `???` (or something else throwing) or `null`, but neither of them will make it green (`eventually`). Probably something along these lines might better express your intent (of course you can create a method too): `verify(barMock).bar() must not(throwA[AssertionError])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assert something for `eventually`, `success` is a good case for that, as before the `verify` will fail with `AssertionError` when it was not called.

In case you want to be more explicit on that, you can do something like this (based on [this issue](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/395)):

```
eventually {
  verify(barMock).bar() must not(throwA[AssertionError])
}
```